# How to view console after electron application has been packaged

Tags: angularjs, node.js, chromium, electron, electron-builder

Much like the title suggests, I have made a node / angular application using electron.  This application functions as expected when it is run via the `electron ./app` command.  However when it is built (either by electron-packager or by electron-builder) the application will run but no content is displayed.

I would like to be able to see what is actually causing the application to fail, but I am unable to view the console to do that.  Is there any way around this?  Either via a special way to build or via an unknown trick to view the developer tools.

Comment: Did you set as the app to open the developer tools at even production app?

Answer (score 1):

In your menu, add the following :

```
{ role: 'toggledevtools'}
```

You can open dev tools either by navigating to the menu item or cmd + shift + i  if you are on mac/ ctrl + I on windows.

OR

Just use

```
mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()
```

That should do it.